# OpenCV: Setting MatOfKeyPoints from Image Data

Tags: java, image, opencv, mask

I've created a FeatureDetector in OpenCV. Now I don't want to use all of the Key points. Therefore I decided to use a mask. Now I have 2 Problems:

1. Do I work with the MatOfKeyPoint or with the Mat class which both are in the OpenCV core.

2. How do I set up the mask from data out of a picture wich contains binary information?

Here is what I have so far

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public static void run() {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    String sourcePath = "pic.png";
    Features2d features2d = new Features2d();
    Mat srcImgMat = Highgui.imread(sourcePath);
    if (srcImgMat == null) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load image at " + sourcePath);
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Loaded image at " + sourcePath);

    MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    FeatureDetector blobDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.DENSE);  

    blobDetector.detect(srcImgMat, matOfKeyPoints);
    //============================================================================================================
    MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPointsSecond = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    Mat mask = new Mat();

    //picture with binary data
    File file = new File("binary.jpg");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```